# Необходима помощь в отладке функции js

Tags: javascript

Есть метод:

```
Menu.prototype.init = function () {
        var self = this;
        function sliding(item, step) {
            var i = 0;
            var imgs = Array.prototype.slice.apply(item.querySelectorAll('img'));
            var len = imgs.length;
            function next() {
                imgs[i].style.opacity = 0;
                if(i == len - 1) {
                    imgs[0].style.opacity = 1;
                } else {
                    imgs[i+1].style.opacity = 1;
                }
               i++;
               if(i == len) {
                   i = 0;
               }
                console.log(i);
            }
            setInterval(next, step);
        }
        function start(items, step) {
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                step += 200;
                (function(i, step) {
                    sliding(items[i], step);
                })(i, step);
            }
        }
        start(this.items, 3000);

    }
```

Метод работает но не так как задумывалось, я так понимаю дело в таймерах..
Задумка была, что бы картинки менялись последовательно и при первом запуске так и происходит... но дальше они начинают меняться хаотично. Подскажите направление поиска решения?
Посмотреть работу скрипта можно [здесь](http://rost-npk.ru/)

Comment: поставте заместо сетИнтервал сетТаймоут

Comment: @L. Vadim  что это даст?

Comment: последовательность выполнения функции
@pepel_xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для это setTimeout вместо интервала. Просто потому, что при setInterval будет запускаться след. функция, даже если прошлая не успела закончиться, вот в этом вся и проблема. В вашем коде вы не очищаете "таймер". Вы должны его очищать, чтоб была хоть какая-та последовательность.
Вот мой пример, только с рекурсивным setTimeout.
В этой [статье](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-settimeout) сказано почему setTimeout > setInterval

```js
const imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
let currentTimer;

function carusel(arr) {
  const [head, ...last] = arr;
  if (!head) {
    console.log('элементы закончились, очищаю стили и запускаю по новой.');
    imgs.forEach(el => {
      el.removeAttribute('style');
    });
    currentTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      carusel(imgs);
    }, 200);
  } else {
    head.style.opacity = 1;

    currentTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      carusel(last);
    }, 200);
  }
}

document.querySelector('.start').onclick = function() {
  carusel(imgs);
}

document.querySelector('.stop').onclick = function() {
  clearTimeout(currentTimer);
}
```

```css
img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button class='start'>start</button>
<button class='stop'>stop</button>
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: хорошо бы прикрепить как исполняемый

Comment: не понял вашего комментария.

Comment: с возможностью запуска кода

Comment: @webDev_ у меня код и так в сниппете, вы о чем?

Comment: Да спасибо, я понял про таймер. Но сделал немного подругому.
И у вас изображения в одном диве, у меня 6 дивов в каждом из которых изображения.. и менятся они должны циклично, Первый запуск показались первые изображения, второй вторые и так далее

Comment: эм.. странно.. теперь появилось